# Error : **** has not been declared

Tags: c++

In my Function.h file:

```
class Function{
  public:
    Function();
    int help();
};
```

In my Function.cpp file:

```
#include "Function.h"
int Function::help() //Error here
{
  using namespace std;
  cout << "Help";
  return 1;
}
```

In my Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Function.h"
using namespace std;

int menu(){
  Function fc;
  fc.help();
  return 1;
}

int main(int args, char**argv){
  return menu();
}
```

Error is : ‘Function’ has not been declared

Can anybody tell me why? Thank you.

I tried like this and the problem is solved, but I dont really understand why:
In Function.h file: 
I use

```
class Function{
  public:
    int status;
    Function():status(1){}
    int help();
};
```

instead of the old one

```
class Function{
  public:
    Function();
    int help();
};
```

Comment: Does `function.h` includes some other header file?

Comment: You have edited your question so that the problem vanished. This makes it not more readable. Suggesting to keep the coding errors and write an own answer.

Answer (score 7):

All your include statements are missing the `#`:

```
#include "Function.h"
^
```

Everything else looks fine, though you need to also `#include <iostream>` in Function.cpp since you're using `cout`.

Here is the Function.cpp that I got to compile and run:

```
#include "Function.h"
#include <iostream>

int Function::help() // No error here
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Help";
    return 1;
}

Function::Function()
{
}
```

Comment: ah thanks, but # is missed because I couldnot type it here, I had it in my file

Comment: @user: Hmm, I'm at a loss then. Are you sure the code you posted reproduces the error? Is there any other code in Function.cpp?

Comment: @user: OK, I copied your code into a test project. I needed to add the `#include <iostream>` and the constructor definition to make it compile (and link), but otherwise it works fine

Comment: @user: Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem. I've edited my answer to include the changes I had to make for it to compile

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. Make sure that you only have the required header files.  I had two header files both including each other and it spit out this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a declaration for the constructor of the Function class without including it in your implementation (cpp file).

```
#include "Function.h"

Function::Function(){
    // construction stuff here
}

int Function::help() //Error here
{
using namespace std;
cout << "Help";
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Good point, but that shouldn't be causing the error (that's a link-time error)

Comment: When I tried as u told, I had the following errors<br/> ‘Function’ has not been declared/
ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Function’ with no type/
‘Function’ is not a class or namespace/

Answer (score 2):

In the first Function.h file you have declared the constructor but not defined it. In the second Function.h file (the one that works) you have defined and declared the Function constructor. You can either define and declare in the header or file, or declare in the header file and define in the Function.cpp file.

For example, declare in the header file "Function.h":

```
    class Function
    {
    Function();
    }
```

and define here in "Function.cpp":

```
    Function::Function(){}
```

Or the alternative is to declare and define in the header file "Function.h":

```
    Class Function
    {
    Function(){}
    }
```

The other thing that you have done in the second version of the header file is to initialise the member variable "status" in the "member initialisation list" which is a good thing to do (See Effective C++ by Scott Meyers, Item 4). Hope this helps :)